# Javamail rate for the client exceeded

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I need to send at least 200 messages from a stretch. When the program starts, send mail successfully to 15 or 17, then I get this error:

MESSAGE ERROR:

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 421 4.4.2 Message submission rate for this client has exceeded the configured limit
```

What I can do?

## CODE JAVA

```
public void mandarEmail(String correos, String mensaje, String asunto) {
    Message message;
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "pod51004.outlook.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("docemail@usmp.pe", "docpass");
        }
    });

    try {
        message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("USMP - FN <documentos-fn@usmp.pe>"));
        message.setSubject(asunto);
        message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(correos));
        message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress[]{new InternetAddress("ivan_pro_nice@hotmail.com")});
        message.setContent(mensaje, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect("docemail@usmp.pe", "docpass");
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        props = null;
        message = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: So don't send so much mail at once. This is the server telling you you're spamming.

Comment: Stop spamming, basically. Rate limit your outgoing email so you don't exceed whatever outlook.com's limits are.

Comment: So you're telling me that I can not send more than 15 emails?

Comment: If you need to send this many (legit) emails and your SMTP server doesn't allow it, possibly look into another service like Mailgun (http://www.mailgun.com/).

Another option is to rate-limit yourself, wait some amount of time (30 seconds?) to keep from tripping the server's rate limit (depending on how it's configured).

Comment: No, more like you can't send 15 emails in 1 seconds. 1 email per second, 2 emails per second, probably ok.

Comment: I did not say that sent 15 email every 2 seconds. I sent 15 emails and I get an error .... The time to send 15 emails is about 10 minutes.

Comment: I like your second solution Taj Morton. I could do something to lessen the process. I'll try. Nevertheless I use glassfish server .. there is nothing wrong with that right?

Answer (score 3):

That's the server you're connecting to, and *not* a client issue. [Here's a doc](http://email.about.com/cs/standards/a/smtp_error_code.htm) on how to parse SMTP codes from the server.

> A mail server will reply to every request a client (such as your email
>   program) makes with a return code. This code consists of three
>   numbers.

In your case, you're getting `421`.

Comment: In your article say: 
421 - The service is not available and the connection will be closed.

So.. It means I can not do anything?

Comment: I suspect that's the case. Throttle your sending would be a good first apprach

Comment: but .. give me a clue ... please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to pay for a "business" account from your mail server vendor so they'll let you send more email.

Comment: Once achieved send 300 emails with the above code within a for (i = 0; i <300). The problem is that it is not safe .... Sometimes the sender and not others. 
I was thinking that something wrong with my code I ... That is the question. If not my code ...... must be my server if my server is not as it should be I have to do slower shipping.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send single email to 200 clients. Than u can add an array of reciever's email addresses of size upto 50.
but i you want to send different msg for each email. Then  you can create a new connection to email server with a counter that counts send emails as well as it counts 15 it should create a new connection.

to test your code use mailtrap.io

Comment: I think your answer was the best of all (in an abstract frame), but I would like to see code. For example .... The "session" variable appearing in my code does not have a method "close", then I would not know how to open another connection if I can not close it.

Comment: I suggest u to use sendGrid to send emails. SendGrid is world leader in email service. Here with a free account u can send daily 200 hundred emails and also 200 within a second of time.